# Cloud SQL - Export to CSV file - How to export NULL as empty value

Tags: mysql, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to export data from Cloud SQL to CSV file storing in cloud storage, following this document: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv#export_data_to_a_csv_file

All null values are exported as **"N** or **\N** based on the escape character. The thing is it always has the **N** character but I want it completely empty, in order to load the csv file to BigQuery external table (which doesn't support null marker option, all empty value will be loaded as null).

For example an exported csv line now:

```
1,"value A",\N,"value B"
```

But I want it like this:

```
1,"value A",,"value B"
```

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try the parameter `--escape="5C"`?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I put the escape character 5C and it produces \N for NULL. As I mentioned, it always has the character N after the escape character.

Comment: Empty is not null value. I think it's not possible.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere could you please add your comment as an answer to help the community? Thanks.